# How to update the id attribute on $get callback jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, get

I am trying to update the id attribute of a button on its click event through jquery, the success call is getting executed fine but id attribute is not updating as per the requirement, or is something i am doing wrong on success callback to check the selector class .. ( `$(this).attr("id", "add_"+$id);` )

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.mybtnclass', function( onclick, e){
            $id=$(this).attr('id');
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400);
            $.get('abc.php',{id:$id},function(msg){
                    array=msg.split('/');
            if( msg == 0) // tocheck the value is deleted
                    {
                        $('#'+$id).html('Add ');
                        $('#'+$id).removeClass('btn-danger');
                        $('#'+$id).addClass('btn-success');
                        $(this).attr("id", "add_"+$id);
                        $("#flash").hide();
                    }
            else if( msg == 1) // tocheck the value is added
                    {
                        $('#'+$id).html('Remove');
                        $('#'+$id).removeClass('btn-success');
                        $('#'+$id).addClass('btn-danger');
                        $(this).attr("id", "delete_"+$id);
                        $("#flash").hide();
                    }
            });

                });

            });
    </script>
```

HTML

....

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-<?php echo in_array($q->id, $myarray)? 'danger' : 'success' ; ?> btn-sm mybtnclass"  id="<?php echo in_array($q->id, $myarray)? 'delete_'.$q->id : 'add_'.$q->id ; ?>">  <?php echo in_array($q->id, $myarray)? 'Remove ' : 'Add' ; ?> </button>
```

abc.php

```
<?php 

    $getval=explode('_', $_GET['id']);
    $id=$getval['1'];
    $action = $getval['0'];

    if($action == 'delete')
    {
            //code for delete
            echo 'add/'.$id ;

    }
else
{
  // code to add ...
   echo 'delete/'.$id ;
}

?>
```

Comment: How are you testing to see that the id isn't updated?

Comment: Do you even need the id? why are you changing it?

Comment: Its like adding and deleting a value .. on click it must pass the id everytime to get updated to db

Comment: Right, but why should the id change? if it's the same element, there's no reason to change it's id. Surely you're not using the id for styles or event delegation

Comment: ya name was easy without any heck Thanks @KevinB  Now I completely moved to name part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe the problem you have is about "this"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.mybtnclass', function( onclick, e){
        $id=$(this).attr('id');
        var $this_obj = $(this); // save this to a variable
        $.get('abc.php',{id:$id},function(msg){
                // use $this_obj instead of $(this)
                // because now you are in another block, 'this' is different
        });

            });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `$('#'+$id)` for other oprations. Use it for changing id also

```
$('#'+$id).prop("id", "add_"+$id);
```

*OTHERWISE*

```
var self = this; //Create another variable
$.get('abc.php',{id:$id},function(msg){
    $(self).attr("id", "add_"+$id); //Use other variable to perform operation
});
```

Comment: as per id its still showing error , will be checking the rootcasue for of now i changed everything to name attr Thnaks for second option

Answer (score 0):

Not as per the question asked but still a working method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mybtnclass').click(function(){
            $id=$(this).attr('name');
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400);
            $.getJSON('abc.php',{id:$id},function(data){
            alert(data.action + '-' + data.id); // to troubleshoot
            if( data.action == "add")
                    {
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').html('Add ');
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').removeClass('btn-danger');
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').addClass('btn-success');
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').attr('name', data.action+'_'+data.id);


                    }
            else if( data.action == "delete")
                    {
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').html('Remove');
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').removeClass('btn-success');
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').addClass('btn-danger');
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        $('[name ='+ $id +']').attr('name', data.action+'_'+data.id);

                    }
            });
```

I am passing the value from abc.php as

```
echo json_encode( array("action"=>"add","id"=>$id) );
```